# Common Remote Database connect to Django

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I'm new to Django, I would like to start a project with my friend where we would need to have a database. We are thinking how to do it. Is there any remote database where we can save and share data at once.
Thank you

Comment: You mean like every database server?

Comment: Im not sure how database server works, we used to work with postgres on local PC, but now starting a new project and would like to have something online where we both can share data.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can not give you guidance through the basic of databases here. You have to ask a question about a specific problem you encountered while writing code.

Comment: What you can do is host a database somewhere and share db connection creds. You can create a free tier on heroku and it in your projects db settings. I believe you are working on the same project.

https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql